# Asus laption integrated camera not detected

Tags: drivers, camera

Laptop Asus UX330UAR. Integrated webcam is not detected by the OS - Ubuntu 18.04.
Both Cheese and guvcview complain - no device.

Q: What to check/try for fixing? Considering it was definitely working with Ubuntu 16.04...

All checks made after fresh reboot.

I wasn't expected that, but seems `uvcvideo` is not loaded after start up:

```bsh
sudo rmmod uvcvideo
rmmod: ERROR: Module uvcvideo is not currently loaded
```

load module and list

```bsh
sudo modprobe uvcvideo
andrey@andrey-UX330UAR:~$ lsmod | grep video
uvcvideo               86016  0
videobuf2_vmalloc      16384  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_memops       16384  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
videobuf2_v4l2         24576  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_core         40960  2 videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo
videodev              184320  3 videobuf2_core,videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo
media                  40960  2 videodev,uvcvideo
video                  45056  2 asus_wmi,i915
```

Some more lists:

```bsh
andrey@andrey-UX330UAR:~$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v6/7th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 08)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 620 (rev 07)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 08)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 21)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem (rev 21)
00:15.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 21)
00:15.1 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #1 (rev 21)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI #1 (rev 21)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 21)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev f1)
00:1c.6 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #7 (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Intel(R) 100 Series Chipset Family LPC Controller/eSPI Controller - 9D4E (rev 21)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PMC (rev 21)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus (rev 21)
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 8260 (rev 3a)
andrey@andrey-UX330UAR:~$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 04f3:0903 Elan Microelectronics Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 8087:0a2b Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
andrey@andrey-UX330UAR:~$ ls -l /dev/video*
ls: cannot access '/dev/video*': No such file or directory
```

Not sure if it's relevant. During boot:

```bsh
dmesg | grep -iP 'Camera|video'
[    0.076109] ACPI: Added _OSI(Linux-Dell-Video)
[    0.245156] pci 0000:00:02.0: Video device with shadowed ROM at [mem 0x000c0000-0x000dffff]
[    2.397326] ACPI: Video Device [GFX0] (multi-head: yes  rom: no  post: no)
[    2.397612] input: Video Bus as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/LNXVIDEO:00/input/input5
[  558.305783] Linux video capture interface: v2.00
[  558.317146] usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo
[  558.317148] USB Video Class driver (1.1.1)
[  942.571630] usbcore: deregistering interface driver uvcvideo
[  942.795701] Linux video capture interface: v2.00
[  942.808852] usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo
[  942.808853] USB Video Class driver (1.1.1)
```

And then in dmesg..

```bsh
usb 1-5: new full-speed USB device number 58 using xhci_hcd
```

Could be informative...

```bsh
modinfo uvcvideo
filename:       /lib/modules/4.15.0-96-generic/kernel/drivers/media/usb/uvc/uvcvideo.ko
version:        1.1.1
license:        GPL
description:    USB Video Class driver
author:         Laurent Pinchart <laurent.pinchart@ideasonboard.com>
srcversion:     41E18BDF365D37D85A6A70D
```

Syslog on rm and probe of the module:

```bsh
Apr 18 17:48:47 andrey-UX330UAR kernel: [ 2102.039692] usbcore: deregistering interface driver uvcvideo
Apr 18 17:48:48 andrey-UX330UAR kernel: [ 2102.277915] media: Linux media interface: v0.10
Apr 18 17:48:48 andrey-UX330UAR kernel: [ 2102.294165] Linux video capture interface: v2.00
Apr 18 17:48:48 andrey-UX330UAR kernel: [ 2102.306435] usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo
Apr 18 17:48:48 andrey-UX330UAR kernel: [ 2102.306436] USB Video Class driver (1.1.1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like that's HW problem. Probably due to quite limited angle (as designed) of opening of the monitor-cover some bus-cables damaged.